# Copying data from database to excel file , it is taking too much time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

i wanted to copy data from database to excel file, i was using loop to do that but it is taking too much time when there are lots of rows in database, please kindly suggests me any alternatives thank you

```
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                    Workbook xlWorkBook;
                    Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                    xlWorkBook = xapp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                    xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3);
                    xlWorkSheet.Name = "Customer Details";
                    //*********************************************gettting data from sql database to  worksheet*********
                    sqlconn.Open();
                    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from customer ", sqlconn);

                    sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "S.No.";
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Customer ID";
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Customer Name";
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Address";
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Country";

                    int i = 1;
                    int j = 0;
                    while (sqlreader.Read())
                    {
                        i++;
                        for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = sqlreader.GetValue(j).ToString();
                    }

                    sqlreader.Close();
                    sqlconn.Close();
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\"+fileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xapp.Quit();
```

Comment: how long is too much time? how many rows are lots of rows?

Comment: What would you use the output for? Is it one time or you need to automate the exporting?

Comment: For 7,000 rows it is taking more than 15 minutes i guess

Comment: *Don't* use Excel Interop for this. Use a libary like EPPlus to create the Excel file directly. It's as easy as `sheet.LoadFromDataReader(sqlReader);`. Another option is to have *Excel* read the data, using a data connection

Comment: BTW 7K rows isn't a lot.

Comment: yeah thats why i need an alternative, rows are not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing values to Excel cells individually is always very slow.  A lot faster is to use a range.  The syntax for this is:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range aRange = ws.get_Range(startCell, lastCell);
aRange.Value2 = args;
```

args is an `object[,]` which you create from your data (my preference here is to use a `DataTable` instead of a `Reader`, because it makes it easier to dimension the array prior to populatuing - you have access to `Columns.Count` and `Rows.Count`).

startCell and lastCell are in Excel "A1" format. I have a handy little method that returns "A1" format from r1c1 format, which is quite useful when the columns and rows are dynamic, particularly for calculating the last cell in the range.

```
private string GetCellName(int row, int col)
{
    string result;
    char[] letters = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N',
        'O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    int offset = 0;
    while (col > 26)
    {
        col -= 26;
        offset++;
    }
    result = "";
    if (offset > 0)
    {
        result += letters[offset - 1];
    }
    result += letters[col - 1];
    result += row.ToString();
    return (result);
}
```

HTH

EDIT

To convert a `DataTable` to `object[,]`, I use something like this:

```
private object[,] DataTableToObjArr(System.Data.DataTable dt)
{
    int colCount = 0;
    int rowCount = 0;
    var args = new object[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count]; 
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        colCount = 0;
        object[] items = dr.ItemArray;

        foreach (object o in items)
        {
            string nextItem = "";

            if (o is DateTime)
            {
                DateTime test = (DateTime)o;
                if ((test.Hour == 0) && (test.Minute == 0) && (test.Second == 0))
                {
                    nextItem = ((DateTime)o).ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
                }
                else
                {
                    nextItem = ((DateTime)o).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nextItem = o.ToString();
            }
            args[rowCount, colCount] = nextItem;

            colCount++;
        }

        rowCount++;
    }
    return args;
}
```

You will notice that I differentiate between `DateTime` and other object types.  In my experience most types can be passed as is into the object array.  I find that Excel does odd things with `DateTimes` that are really just dates, so I treat them as a special case.

Comment: How can i use datatable to store value ... xlWorkSheet.get_Range("R7618", "C18").Value = dtable; , its getting exception

Comment: get_Range takes start cell, end cell, so I presume you need get_range("C18", "R7618")

Comment: Please see my Edit for converting DataTable to object array.  Also I found Range.Value2 worked better.